Video with Audio Works After Logging In and Out, But Not Initially in React Application
Description:
I'm encountering a peculiar issue with a video component in my React application. The video plays fine with audio, but only after I log in and then log out. Initially, when the component mounts, there's no audio. I'm using the <video> tag to embed the video with the source provided as an MP4 file. Here's the relevant code snippet:
<video autoPlay loop muted id="backgroundVideo">
  <source
    src="https://example.com/my-video.mp4"
    type="video/mp4"
  />
</video>

Problem:

The video plays correctly with audio only after logging in and then
logging out.
Initially, when the component mounts, there's no audio.
I've verified that the MP4 file itself has audio when played outside
of the application.
I'm using the muted attribute in the <video> tag to ensure that
autoplay works, but even removing it doesn't enable the audio
initially.

Expected Behavior:
The video should play with audio when the component is mounted, without requiring any user action such as logging in and out.
Demo Video:
Link to Demo Video
Additional Context:

I'm using React with a login/logout mechanism.
The issue occurs consistently across different browsers.
I've checked for any side effects related to the login/logout
mechanism, but couldn't identify the root cause.

Full Code is

import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
//import { login } from "../../context/authContext/apiCalls";
import { AuthContext } from "../../context/authContext/AuthContext";
import "./Login.scss";
import { loginCall } from "../../context/authContext/apiCall";

export default function Login() {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const { isFetching, dispatch } = useContext(AuthContext);

  const handleLogin = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    loginCall({ email, password }, dispatch);
  };

useEffect(() => {
  const video = document.getElementById("backgroundVideo");
  video.play();
}, []);
//const IMG = 'https://e1.pxfuel.com/desktop-wallpaper/685/766/desktop-wallpaper-backgrounds-for-name.jpg';
  return (
    <div className='Login'>
      <video autoPlay loop  id="backgroundVideo">
        <source
          src="https://vod-progressive.akamaized.net/exp=1712081324~acl=%2Fvimeo-prod-skyfire-std-us%2F01%2F3826%2F13%2F344134811%2F1379650086.mp4~hmac=3cf273be44a5d0e94da54f9a3e2225c20f46ed71383b14ddcf178b0d271c5650/vimeo-prod-skyfire-std-us/01/3826/13/344134811/1379650086.mp4"
          type="video/mp4"
        />
      </video>
        <div className="top">
             <div className="wrapper">
                <img className='logo' src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/08/Netflix_2015_logo.svg" alt="" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div className="continer">
            <form>
                <h1>Login</h1>
                <input type="email" placeholder="Enter your email" onChange={(e)=> setEmail(e.target.value)}/>
                <input type="password" placeholder="password" onChange={(e)=> setPassword(e.target.value)}/>
                <button className="loginbutton" onClick={handleLogin} disabled={isFetching}>Let Me In.</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
  );
}

